# How to inherit from class that could be inherited by other classes and keep other classes properties (for view model)

Tags: c#, oop, viewmodel, multiple-inheritance

I'm stuck in my inheritances bloating here:

First let me explain the premise of my problem.
My Model:

```
public class Person
{      
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class SuperHero:Person
{    
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string SuperHeroName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SuperPower> SuperPowers{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to create my viewModels for my MVC website, I have those base classes that need to be inherited by all other viewmodel displaying/editing a Person/SuperHero:

```
public class BasePersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    ctors()
}

public class BaseSuperHeroViewModel : BasePersonViewModel
{
    public List<string> SuperPowers{ get; set; }
    ctors() 
}
```

Here is where I am stuck, I am trying to define only one ViewModel that could be used regarless of the base class and access property of Person and/or SuperHero (if the Person is a superhero). I've been pulling my hair out but so far only found a solution which i don't like:

Example:

```
public class SomeViewModel<T> where T : BasePersonViewModel
{
    public BasePersonViewModel obj;
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public SomeViewModel(Person data) //: base(data)
    {
        if (data is SuperHero)
            obj = new BaseSuperHeroViewModel (data);
        else
            obj = new BasePersonViewModel(data);
    }
}
```

While this would work it's really not sexy to use. And on top of that, I could have another ViewModel that inherit from SomeViewModel as well.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

**Edit** 
My main goal is to be able to able to cast my SomeViewModel depending on the one of the baseclass. Let's say do something like in my Controller:

```
if myclass is SomeViewModel (of type SuperHero)
```

Exactly how you do it for Person/SuperHero db retrival/check

```
var data = context.Person.first(w=> w.Id==1)
if (data is SuperHero)
..
```

I would like this because I would like to use the same viewmodel let's say to list superhero and person, and just display slightly differently if it's a superhero

**Edit 2**
I was trying to avoid using the whole Model.Obj to be able to see it directly with the Model... But the more i think about it, the more I think this is not possible really... On top of that I would like to extend some other superHero specific properties in SomeViewModel (only if SomeViewModel is a superhero), that are not declared in the BaseSuperHeroModel one... Let's say in SomeViewModel I want the field 'ComesFromPlanet' only if superhero.

**Edit 3**
I thought about another way to do it, but it obviously creating various ViewModel.
For the most general case (all fields that are shared for all Person) I would keep my base:

```
public class BasePersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    ctors()
}
```

I interface specific Person:

```
public Interface IBaseSuperHero
{    
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string SuperHeroName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SuperPowers{ get; set; }
}
```

I would keep as well OtherViewModel like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel:BasePersonViewModel
{    
    Public datetime Birthdate {get;set;}
}
```

Then I would create a specific SomeviewModel for other Person inheritant and used interfaces to have old and new properties.
For example:

```
public class SomeViewModelSuperHero:SomeViewModel, IBaseSuperHero
{   
  public string OriginalPlanet {get;set;}
}
```

Is this a clean solution?

Sorry I'm sure I am not clear about this, but I try !

Thanks for your input and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to define only one ViewModel that could be used regarless of the base class and access property of Person and/or SuperHero (if the Person is a superhero)

Assuming you'd return default values for super-hero properties when the model is not a super-hero, you could do something like this:

```
public class PersonOrSuperHeroViewModel {
  private Person person;
  private SuperHero superHero;

  public PersonOrSuperHeroViewModel(Person personOrSuperHero) {
    if (personOrSuperHero is SuperHero) superHero = personOrSuperHero;
    person = personOrSuperHero;
  }

  public IsSuperHero { get { return superHero != null; } }

  ... // super-hero properties only work when IsSuperHero == true
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. The problem is that my Person class could be used for other classes than hero, let's say 'VideoGameHero', 'WarHero', and so on.. would make a lot of code. And I would like to do in my Controller/View something like if Model = SomeViewModelPerson or Model = SomeViewModelSuperhero.. (hope this makes sense, thanks )

Comment: Trying to avoid, separate viewModel, I would like to use same view model, that i would not need to update if I create another class inheriting from Person.

Comment: If you create other person classes with unique properties, the only way to have a single view model that you don't need to change is to have some kind of hash table or dynamic object.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about a list/dic of properties, but I'd rather use flat properties... II think I'll just create several ViewModels like you suggested. I updated my question with an idea of what I could do. Or extend Stochastically’s answer… I’m not sure what the best.

Comment: Gonna do about what you said, except i m gonna put all my Properties in my BasePerson (hero or not) and fill them if needed and put what kind of person it is in another variable. not sexy but i think it will save me a lot of time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
public class Person {
    public virtual BasePersonViewModel MainViewModel {
        get { return new BasePersonViewModel(this);}
    }
}

public class SuperHero : Person {
    public override BasePersonViewModel MainViewModel {
        get { return new BaseSuperHeroViewModel(this);}
    }
}
```

So if all your people classes override the MainViewModel property to return the appropriate view, you don't need

```
public BasePersonViewModel obj;
public SomeViewModel(Person data) {
    if (data is SuperHero)
        obj = new BaseSuperHeroViewModel (data);
    else
        obj = new BasePersonViewModel(data);
}
```

Because you can have

```
public BasePersonViewModel obj;
public SomeViewModel(Person data) { obj = data.MainViewModel; }
```

which will work however many subclasses of person you have.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how to inherit this on other subViewModels

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but I've expanded my answer to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's a better way than my Generic. so to know if the person in someviewModel is a superhero i would need to do Model.Obj is superHero. I was trying to avoid using the whole Model.Obj to be able to see it directly with the Model... But the more i think about it, the more I think this is not possible really... Because I would like to show some other superHero specific properties in SomeViewModel (only if SomeViewModel is a superhero), that are not declared in the BaseSuperHeroModel one... Oy... thanks